# How do I use STL's copy() to create a new vector from an existing vector?

Tags: c++, stl

Say I have a `std::vector` called `vec` with 10 elements and I want to create a new `std::vector` containing all elements between (and including) the 2nd and 5th elements of vec. I can see how I might write a `for` loop to do this, but it looks like STL's `copy()` can do this more concisely. But I'm not really getting iterators: I've seen how you can use `start()` and `end()` to iterate over a vector from its first to last element, but what about the situation above, where I want something slightly different? Thanks.

Comment: See the example here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need `std::copy` to create a new `vector` with a subset of the first one. You can achieve this with the `vector`'s constructor and its iterators ([doc here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/)):

```
std::vector<myType> vec = ...;
std::vector<myType> other(vec.begin() + 1, vec.begin() + 5);
```

You have to be sure though, that you don't exceed the `vector`'s limits, or you will get undefined behavior.

Comment: To include the the 5th element, you need `+ 5` instead of `+ 4`.

Comment: Oh, OK, I can just do arithmetic on iterators, similar to using pointer arithmetic to index arrays in C. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris You can do arithmetic on iterators for `std::vector`.  This isn't a universal property of iterators; only random access iterators support addition and subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Constantinus is right with his answer - you don't need copy.

But in case of a different situation, where you want to append elements you can use this:

```
std::vector< type > vec = ... ;
std::vector< type > othervec = ...;
std::copy( vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::back_inserter(othervec) );
```